# Second fundamental form as a function?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am having trouble understanding how the fundamental forms, in particular the second fundamental form, can be used as functions.

In the textbook I am using I see often this $II_P(v)$ where $v$ is a vector in the tangent space of the surface at $P$.

Now the way I know how to derive the second fundamental form is this:

Assume $X(u(t), v(t))$ is an arc length parametrized curve on a surface $S$. The second fundamental form is:

Find the curvature scaled normal of the curve by computing $X''(u(t), v(t))$ Then calculate $\langle X''(u(t), v(t)), \hat n \rangle$ where $\hat n$ is the unit length normal of the surface at $P$.

This will yield:

$kN \cdot \hat n = \hat n \cdot X_{uu}\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial t ^2} +2\hat n \cdot X_{uv}\frac{\partial u\partial v}{\partial t ^2} + \hat n \cdot X_{vv}\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial t ^2} + \underbrace{\hat n \cdot X_u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t ^2}}_{=0} + \underbrace{\hat n \cdot X_v\frac{\partial^2 d}{\partial t ^2}}_{=0} = k\cos(\theta)$

The last 2 terms are 0 because they are orthogonal to the normal by definition, and $ \theta$ Is the angle between the surface normal and the curve normal.

You can then sub $L, M, N$ into the formula to obtain the textbook definition.
$II = Ldu^2 + 2Mdudv + Ndv^2 = k\cos(\theta)$

Well, I don't see how the second fundamental form is used as map based on the above.

Comment: The shape operator is the linear map associated to this bilinear (quadratic) form. $T(v)\cdot w = II(v,w)$. See my diff geo text, (freely) linked in my profile.

Comment: Oh I am realizing that I am mixing the shape operator and the second fundamental form and they are not the same.